# Couchbase - Eviction

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

Couchbase stores the data in the disk and also retains it in the RAM. Once high watermark is reached , I guess it starts the eviction process. I assume the data would also be in the disk at this point. So does eviction really mean deletion of message from RAM? Or does mean deletion of data from RAM  and writing it to disk? If it also includes writing it to disk , why should data already present in the disk be overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase only evicts documents that have been persisted to disk. As you say, eviction means clearing the document data from RAM. When using the value eviction strategy, which is the default, Couchbase keeps the key and metadata in RAM and only evicts the document value. With the full eviction strategy, it deletes both the key, metadata and value from RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase first writes to RAM and then asynchronously writes to disk as well. Depending on the configuration you can have document along with metadata of the document in the RAM. And, yes when the **threshold** (High Water Mark) reaches Couchbase will start evicting the data (value and/or metadata as per configuration) from RAM until it reaches Low Water Mark.